# EasyUI add tab event

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

In the EasyUI, I need to add a new tab to load jsp file, how to add an event like afterAdd ? I need to load remote data after this 'add' .

Thanks.

```
$('#tabContainer').tabs('add', {
            title: 'Personal Account ' + id,
            href: 'personalAccountForm.jsp?id='+id,
            closable: true           
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

onAdd Fires when a new tab panel is added.

```
    $('#').tabContainer({  onAdd : function(title,index){.....
```